# Android Studio new project file size too big

Tags: android, android-studio

I just created a new android project in Android Studio 2.2.3 with just an empty Activity and still it uses 4.11 MB on the device which I think is a lot given that it does contain a single empty Activity. Why is it taking so much space? Is it possible to reduce its size? I have downloaded applications with more functionality and which have more pictures, colors, etc. and are less than 2MB.

Bellow are the steps I used to create the project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then, after running the application on a Sony Xperia I get this information.

[image]

And when profiling the memory I get.

[image]

Which has allocated 3MB and ust 1MB free.

This is the build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.survey.research.surveycollect"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: "Why is it taking so much space?" -- most likely you wound up with `appcompat-v7`, which will contribute ~1MB to the APK size. I recommend that you edit your question and post your `app/build.gradle` file, so we can see what dependencies you have.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated the question to include the build.gradle file.

Comment: `appcompat-v7` will add ~1MB to your APK, and `design` should add ~300KB. You can use Build > Analyze APK in Android Studio 2.2+ to see how big your actual APK is and where the space is going. You do not have to use `appcompat-v7` or `design` (though `design` requires `appcompat-v7`); you got those by your choices when setting up the initial activity. In Android Studio 2.2.3, setting up a new project, choosing the Empty Activity template, and unchecking the "Backwards compatibility" checkbox will skip `appcompat-v7` (and Empty Activity should not pull in `design` in any case).

Answer (score 1):

Enable minify and resources shrinking in your build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

It will remove unused code and resources from your apk

Answer (score 1):

Debug apk or release apk? If debug apk its always slightly bigger than release. In release mode, do `minifyEnabled = true`, `shrinkResources = true`, `zipAlignEnabled = true`. It will shrunk your release file size to around 30% (base on my exp) of your debug files.