# Simple Hello World project turns into a 7 MB app

Tags: android, installation, size

I made a simple 'Hello World' project on Android 3.0.1 and for some reason the size of it is 6.8MB. Why is that?
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180070/android-studio-new-project-file-size-too-big) similar question but it didn't help

This is the build.gradle file:

```
    android
    {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.abc.testing"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes
        {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
dependencies
    {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

here is the [app-debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRsqM.png)

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR1Es.png) is the size after installation

Comment: remove testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

Comment: @MaxAves I've tried that but it didn't effect the size at all

Comment: i agree with @MaxAves
some time library can increase the app size.

also folow this link : https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Comment: You have minify enabled for release build type only - try assembleRelease.

Comment: You are measuring the debug apk. The debug apk has a lot of stuff for debug purpose. Please go to build -> generate signed apk to generate a release apk.

Comment: At first thats what I thought but I never added any libraries and also tried remove unnecessary libraries but like I said it didn't reduce the size.

Comment: Create a release APK and look for it here : [project-root]/[app-root]/build/outputs/apk/[app name]-release.apk